# Jquery post in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm new with django and jquery, and I try to implement a very simple $post request.

Here is what I did:

my js:

```
 $.post(/mysite/blabla/, { 
 score : 40
 });
```

my views:

```
 def blabla(request):
    score_user = 20
    if request.method == 'POST':
       score_user = request.POST['score']
```

The console does not indicate any error for the post request. The thing is that when I render "score_user", I always get 20, when I expect to get 40.

Any help would be welcome. Thanks

EDIT:

my model:

```
 class UserProfile(FacebookProfileModel):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User)
      comment = models.BooleanField()
      score = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0)
```

Comment: It happens because in the view function, the value score is somehow not coming in the POST. try printing: print request.POST['score'] and see what you get. On the other hand, I dont know jquery either but dictionary-like objects have the following scheme: { key:value, } where key is almost always a string try: { 'score':40 }

Comment: This is just JavaScript; `{ score: 40 }` and `{ 'score': 40 }` are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.post('/mysite/blabla/', {'score': 40}, function(data) { 
    $('.result').html(data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer is really clear, it helps me a lot. But when I go to my page /mysite/blabla, it still renders 20, and not 40. Is it normal?

Comment: I use SQLite. But in this case, 20 comes from my view. I wanted to do something simple before I try to modify the database directly through the jquery request. But that what I want to do at the end. P.S: I edited my question to show you my model.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I wanted to do! Thank you for your time, you helped me a lot!

Comment: I have one last question. I try to make the score change every 2 seconds. So i put the $post inside a setInterval. It works well, it changes the score at each request. But I would like the new score to be the existing score + new points. So I would like the variable "score" to be added to the score in my database instead of replacing it. I tried to use userprofile.score+= score_user in my view, but it doesn't work. Do you know how to do it? Thank you again for your help, and I swear it's my last question...

Comment: It looks like you've already asked this question under a different user account here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070406/use-the-result-of-an-ajax-request-in-my-views-py-django. Since SO doesn't allow duplicates I think you should delete this question and stay with the original.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $.post("/mysite/blabla/", { score : 40 }, function(data){
   //  alert(data);
     $("#results").html(data);
 });
```

html:

```
Score: <span id='results'></span>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. When I do that, and I go back to the page the html is associated with (not blabla) I have a pop up saying: "Page sur localhost:8000 says:  40". But when I go on mysite/blabla, I still get a 20 rendered in my page.

Comment: Ok, it looks like it renders the html of my /blabla/ in a pop-up. But what I would like to do is to use the post request to modify an object of my Django app. For example, the object score of my user. Do you have any idea on how to do that? Thank you very much!

Comment: yeah on the area where u want to modify depending on the score, suround it with a span or div with an id, like so: score = <span id='results'></span>, then populate it like this: $("#results").html(data); i have refined my answer to help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to url encode the parameters you are passing to the view using `&`. Besides for POST requests the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` is required unless you have disabled it. The `status` will be alerted on request.

```
$.post('/mysite/blabla/','score=40&csrfmiddlewaretoken='+'{{csrfmiddlewaretoken}}').
success(function(data, status, xhr) { alert(status)}).
error(function(data, status, xhr) { alert(status)})
```

The `.success` and `.error` [syntax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is part of jquery [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) interface

Comment: Ok, thank you, it works very well. But now, how can I use this value (score=40) in order to modify one of my object? For example, I if want to replace the score of a user by the score posted by the ajax request?

Comment: @VictoriaBaboule you can access a user in your view by doing `request.user`. Then go ahead and filter your required model say `Player` as `p = Player.object.get(user=user)`, then do a `p.score+=score` and then do a `p.save()`. Exact requirements will vary as per you need, but hope you got the idea.